# Export and download each Sentinel-2 satellite data by date from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, sentinel-2

I would like to download Sentinel-2 satellite data for the year from January 1, 2023 to December 31, 2023 from Google Earth Engine, respectively by date.

I've written and run the script below, and I think maybe a year of data has been consolidated into one. and also, I would like to save each file name as the date the image was created.

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filterDate('2015-01-01', '2023-12-31')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
.filterBounds(roi)
.median();



var visParamsTrue = {bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:2500, gamma:1.1};
Map.addLayer(image, visParamsTrue, 'Sentinel 2A');
Map.addLayer(image.clip(roi), visParamsTrue, 'Research_Area');
Map.centerObject(roi, 10);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image:image.int16(),
  description:'Sentinel_2A',
  scale:10,
  region:roi,
  maxPixels:7699027
});
```